# WPF + MVVM - Access object/property in UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls

I have searched the net for a way to access an object/property within a UserControl. I have a  Page object in my view in wich i load a usercontrol:

```
<UserControl:RichTextEditorControl Height="350" />
```

How do i access an object/property which resides in the viewmodel of my view from my usercontrol? To put my problem in practice: i have a list of items that is displayed in my view, and when i have selected an item, i load the usercontrol. I then want my usercontrol to do "stuff" to the selected item. How can i do this?

Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the selected item be either a Dependency Property on your UserControl, or just be it's DataContext.  You could then just setup the UserControl using binding:

```
<UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding TheSelectedObjectProperty}" />
```

If your list box binds to that same `TheSelectedObjectProperty`, the UserControl will see the selected item when you change items in the list box automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I guess i should've been more specific, so i wouldnt waste your time, but: the thing is that the user control has its own viewmodel, and in the xaml of the usercontrol, the datacontext is set to that viewmodel. So i guess i cant set the datacontext again.

I have tried to make the selected item a dependency property, but i couldnt make it work. I guess there is a possibility that i missed something when trying it though.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe i should also ask if it is possible to use binding with a relative source and findancestor to get the property?

Comment: @user409816: If you make the SelectedItem a dependency property, you should be able to setup the binding to it from teh "container" holding the UserControl.  That will work fine.

Comment: @user409816: This, btw, is effectively a master-detail scenario.  I also wrote an article showing how to use Behaviors to accomplish this.  It might be of use: http://reedcopsey.com/2009/10/14/using-a-behavior-to-aggregate-values-in-a-master-detail-view-in-m-v-vm/

Comment: I'll definitely look in to this.. thank you very much for your help!